# ERROR_DOWNLOAD_TASK_START_ISSUE on System Workbench STM32 Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-cdt, stm32, stm32f4, nucleo

Trying to start a new project for STM32F446RE board for blinking LED. There is an error which restricts me from downloading the firmware. I tried downloading the firmware from STM website and pasting in SystemWorkbench Firmware folder in `AppData`.

[image]

Comment: I don't know why would anybody give you a -1 to your very very important question. This problem is happening to a lot of people. +1 for relevance

Comment: You can find a general solution to this problem in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59897577/error-download-task-start-issue-on-system-workbench-stm32-eclipse-has-not-been-r/59907860#59907860

Answer (score 2):

One can download the zip file at http://www.ebuc23.com/s5/ac6/software/firmware/stm32f4_dsp_stdperiph_lib_v180.zip and paste the Zip file and the extracted file in

C:\Users\User_Name\AppData\Roaming\Ac6\SW4STM32\firmwares

and reopen Eclipse and you are good to go. No need to download CubeHAL.

Comment: How about the firmware for other models?

Comment: how did you get the name of the zip file you need?

Comment: I was watching a tutorial and in that when the tutor created the project the library name was seen. I searched for it. But one can try to download it from the official website. https://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/stm32-standard-peripheral-libraries.html#products.

Comment: @KansaiRobot Your answer in the link seems better and more general and the links to access the files are mentioned in that xml file. Thank you.