# ERROR_DOWNLOAD_TASK_START_ISSUE on System Workbench STM32 Eclipse has not been resolved

Tags: eclipse-cdt, stm32

I have the exact same problem as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59799850/error-download-task-start-issue-on-system-workbench-stm32-eclipse)

The problem is that when downloading the firmware for a STM model in System Workbench, the download fails with ERROR_DOWNLOAS_TASK_START_ISSUE

The reason I post this question again is:

1)The answer given in that question *only works for a particular STM model* A mode general solution is needed

2) This question has been posted by many people having the same issue in the OpenSTM32 COmmunit forum. So far nobody has an answer, and apparently it is a bug preventing many people to use the tool

3) Due to this error, any further developing with System Workbench cannot proceed

Has anybody find a solution to this?

EDIT:
According to the linked question' answer and also to [this thread post](https://www.openstm32.org/tiki-view_forum_thread.php?forumId=7&comments_parentId=5300&threadId=8067&thread_sort_mode=commentDate_asc#threadId=8067) the problem is in the places where the firmware is being searched. So if you go to the stm32targets.xml file (which is hidden) you can see that the firware is in other locations.

The problem is that you have to know the name of the firmware you need, since those locations are not listable. I wonder how to do this.

so far I know one file name and I tried it and downloaded succesfully but how can this work with other STM models

Comment: Where you able to automatically download the target firmware. I am having a similar issue and I have posted the question in the forum. My be you can help me.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue today after installing eclipse on a new computer.
My solution was to reinstall eclipse and use
http://www.ac6-tools.com/Eclipse-updates/org.openstm32.system-workbench.update-site-v2/
as repository.

Comment: Thank you very much!. I did it and it worked! I am going to mark your reply as answer, but I am also go and give more details in another answer.

Comment: Too soon.... I tried with other models and it did not work :(

Answer (score -1):

Jan's answer solved the problem for me! 
I am going to give a bit more detail on how to solve this

First the repository to locate the firmware is
http://www.ac6-tools.com/Eclipse-updates/org.openstm32.system-workbench.update-site-v2/

So go to the file stm32targets.xml (which in my mac system is hidden, I don't know in other systems) under 
SystemWorkbench⁩ ▸ ⁨SystemWorkbench⁩ ▸ ⁨Contents⁩ ▸ ⁨Eclipse⁩ ▸ ⁨plugins⁩ ▸ ⁨fr.ac6.mcu.ide_2.9.0.201904120827⁩ ▸ ⁨resources⁩ ▸ ⁨board_def⁩

and edit the first url in servers with the location above. Then reinitiate System Workbench (I did not reinstall it) and voila it works now.